# Negative cache issue while configuring the Fiori standard application

Tags: sapui5

I am configuring the Manage Purchase Order application in S4HANA 1610 Fiori Launchpad and received `'negative cache'` error. I tried clearing the cache in Gateway server and browser but couldn't resolve the issue. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Error details provided below.

[image]

Error Message:

```
jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:903 2017-10-03 11:45:15.056635 Failed to load UI5 component with 
properties '{"name":"ui.ssuite.s2p.mm.pur.po.create.s1","url":"/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/mm_po_cres1/~F45368EBCCD6942020CB1501EDAA64CB~5","self":{"name":"ui.ssuite.s2p.mm.pur.po.create.s1",
"url":"/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/mm_po_cres1/~F45368EBCCD6942020CB1501EDAA64CB~5"},
"asyncHints":{"libs":[{"name":"sap.m"},{"name":"sap.ui.core"},
{"name":"sap.cus.sd.lib.pricing","url":{"url":"/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/sd_prc_reusels1/~4E8B3849665AC7AE4B1DD376DBC9BFC2~5","final":true}},
{"name":"sap.ssuite.fnd.om.outputcontrol","url":{"url":"/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/fnd_om_out_cls1/~AC18CC9B61A6C691C9AD1253BA4BC5AB~5","final":true}},{"name":"sap.ui.fl"},
{"name":"sap.se.mi.plm.lib.attachmentservice","url":{"url":"/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/plm_ath_cres1/~DB6247A5D1803FA71D7A51D6397AF660~5","final":true}},{"name":"sap.me"},{"name":"sap.ca.scfld.md"},
{"name":"sap.ca.ui"},{"name":"sap.ui.comp"},{"name":"sap.ui.rta","lazy":true},{"name":"sap.suite.ui.microchart","lazy":true},{"name":"sap.ui.table"},
{"name":"sap.ui.unified"},{"name":"sap.ui.layout"}],"components":[{"name":"sap.se.mi.plm.lib.attachmentservice.attachment",
"url":{"url":"/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/plm_ath_cres1/attachment/~DB6247A5D1803FA71D7A51D6397AF660~5","final":true}}],
"requests":[{"name":"sap.ui.fl.changes","reference":"ui.ssuite.s2p.mm.pur.po.create.s1.Component"}],
"waitFor":[]},"componentData":{"startupParameters":{}},
"async":true,"id":"application-PurchaseOrder-manage-component"}'. 
- Error: found in negative cache: 'sap/cus/sd/lib/pricing/library.js' 
from /sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/sd_prc_reusels1/~4E8B3849665AC7AE4B1DD376DBC9BFC2~5/library.js:
 403 - Forbidden
```

Comment: Is this a correct path and filename in your system: “/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/sd_prc_reusels1/~4E8B3849665AC7AE4B1DD376DBC9BFC2~5/library.js”? 403 might happen for a few reasons. It usually means that you don't have the permissions to access the resource.So you might check permissions in your file system. It might also be that the filesystem is incorrect. You might want to check the following: [Error: found in negative cache / failed to load](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3728819)

Comment: Here are some other resources that might be helpful: [Application initialization failed due to an exception: Error found in negative cache](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3745653),  [Error - found in negative cache error for Component.js in custom Fiori app](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3822740) - some additional steps for cache cleaning are mentioned although for solving error 404, and [Something about negative cache error](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/06/03/something-about-negative-cache-error/).